# SP.TimeZone.utcToLocalTime how to use

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

I'm trying to use [SP.TimeZone.utcToLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245318.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) via REST API, but can't understand which format is right for input (with Date and Time).

It works only with date

```
/_api/web/RegionalSettings/TimeZone/utcToLocalTime('3/25/2015')
```

But when I try to pass time it doesn't work, for example:

```
/_api/web/RegionalSettings/TimeZone/utcToLocalTime('3/25/2015, 1:20:00 PM')
/_api/web/RegionalSettings/TimeZone/utcToLocalTime('2015-03-25T13:20:00')
```

Can anyone to help me understand how I can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you can't have `:` in your url path.
However, you can have it in a querystring (not path).
So try this:

```
/_api/web/RegionalSettings/TimeZone/utcToLocalTime(@date)?@date='2015-03-25T13:20:00'
```